# Como corrigir erro em tibble

Tags: r, web-scraping

Estou tentando capturar notícias da Folha de SP, mas o código dá erro na metade.
Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Erro: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
> Size 25: Existing data.
> Size 23: Column at position 2. i Only values of size one are recycled.

Este é o meu código:

```
url_base <- "https://search.folha.uol.com.br/search?q=%22regra%20de%20ouro%22&site=todos&periodo=todos&results_count=695&search_time=1%2C216&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.folha.uol.com.br%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D%2522regra%2520de%2520ouro%2522%26site%3Dtodos%26periodo%3Dtodos&sr="

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
 
dados_pesquisa <- tibble()
 
for (i in 1:28) {
  print(i)
  
  x <- (i-1) * 25+1
  
  url_pesquisa <- paste(url_base, x, sep = "")
pagina <- read_html(url_pesquisa)
  
  nodes_titulos <- html_nodes (pagina, xpath = "//ol/li/div/div/a/h2[@class = 'c-headline__title']")
nodes_links <- html_nodes(pagina, xpath = "//ol/li[@id='view-view']/div/div/a")
  
  titulos <- html_text(nodes_titulos) %>%
    str_squish()
  titulos <- unique(titulos)
  
  links <- html_attr(nodes_links, name = "href")
  links <- unique(links)
  links <- links[!grepl("#foto-", links)]
  
  if(length(titulos)!=length(links)){
    links <- links[!grepl("/galerias/", links)]
  }
 
  tabela_titulos <- tibble(titulos, links)
  
  dados_pesquisa <- bind_rows(dados_pesquisa, tabela_titulos)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no seguinte trecho do código:

```r
titulos <- html_text(nodes_titulos) %>%
  str_squish()
titulos <- unique(titulos)
  
links <- html_attr(nodes_links, name = "href")
links <- unique(links)
links <- links[!grepl("#foto-", links)]
```

Ao utilizar `unique` para os títulos e links da pesquisa, a fim de remover as entradas duplicadas, o nem sempre os tamanhos dos objetos `titulos` e `links` ficam compatíveis.

Houve uma tentativa de consertar isso, com o trecho de código a seguir:

```r
if(length(titulos)!=length(links)){
  links <- links[!grepl("/galerias/", links)]
}
```

Entretanto, ele não considera todos os casos em que este tipo de erro pode ocorrer. Por isso, recomendo substituir o trecho de código acima pela minha sugestão abaixo:

```r
if(length(titulos)!=length(links)){
  links <- links[!grepl("/galerias/", links)]
  links <- links[!grepl("aovivo.folha.uol.com.br", links)]
}
```

Ainda assim, o código não roda para anos anteriores a 2015. Isso se deve aos links da própria Folha. Por exemplo, diversos títulos únicos estão associados a dois links diferentes (resultados de títulos e links intercalados para ilustrar o problema):

```r
 [1] "Primária mantém Cristina viva"                                           

 [1] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/clovisrossi/2015/08/1663587-primaria-mantem-cristina-viva.shtml"                                            
 [2] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/mundo/228236-primaria-mantem-cristina-viva.shtml"       

###

 [4] "Ocidentalismo"                                                           

 [5] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/demetriomagnoli/2015/01/1576506-ocidentalismo.shtml"                                                        
 [6] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/poder/204318-ocidentalismo.shtml"  

###

[11] "Diretor da OMC 'joga a toalha' em principal aposta comercial brasileira" 

[15] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/mercado/2014/10/1533718-diretor-da-omc-joga-a-toalha-em-principal-aposta-comercial-brasileira.shtml"                
[16] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/mercado/191026-diretor-da-omc-joga-a-toalha-em-principal-aposta-comercial-brasileira.shtml"  

###

[14] "Queremos Lula e FHC como aliados, diz conselheiro econômico de Marina"   

[20] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2014/08/1505301-queremos-lula-e-fhc-como-aliados-diz-conselheiro-economico-de-marina.shtml"                   
[21] "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/poder/182333-queremos-lula-e-fhc-como-aliados-no-governo.shtml"
```

Para resolver este problema, é necessário encontrar uma forma de distinguir entre títulos iguais, mas com links ligeiramente diferentes. Infelizmente, eu não saberia como fazer isso sem ter que pensar muito a respeito.